# Can I override the default DNS settings on an HTC Evo without root access?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, networking, htc-evo, dns

Is there any way to override the Sprint DNS server(s) used by default on the 3G connection of an HTC Evo running Froyo without root access?

The reason I want to do this is because some sites are able to resolve when I'm using OpenDNS or Google DNS while connected via WiFi at home, but when I'm on 3G, the same sites come up as page not found, so the easiest culprit to blame is DNS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything I've seen suggests you can only do it if your phone is rooted.  [Here's a tutorial](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/09/how-to-change-dns-server-on-android.html) for those with rooted phones.

Comment: Bummer...I am pretty sure you're right. Thanks for the link, though!

Answer (score 0):

As this question got very old but seems to be the first result when searching for **DNS** setting on **both wifi and mobile**, I would like to answer this to provide a more up-to-date result - I also searched for myself earlier. First of all full disclosure: I'm the author of the app, which can provide this also **without root**. Take a look at [Lilly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aykutcevik.dnssetter), this may help you to set your DNS settings.